# Does length of number affects sorting time?

Tags: sorting, hardware

I have a simple question does the length of numbers that need to be sorted affects the sorting time ??
Example: Suppose we need to sort 10 million 6 digit numbers (like: 204134) and 10 million 2/3 digit numbers(like: 24, 143) and to sort both the sets individually. Does the set with 6 digit numbers is gonna take more time than the the one with 2/3 digit numbers ?

I know the hardware use each logic gate for a single digit so 6 logic gates for 6 digits compared to 2/3 gates for other set but i don't know whether this affects the sorting time or not. Can someone explain me this.
Helps will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What language are you performing this sort in? (and/or what hardware specifically is it running on?)

Comment: On a standard x86 or similar processor, it depends entirely on the sorting algorithm, but I would very much expect the one with smaller numbers to take _more_ time due to collisions.  However, if done entirely in specialized hardware, it... still depends on the algorithm, but I would expect the smaller numbers to be faster.  Are you talking about hardware specially designed to sort a million 6 digit numbers, or a generic purpose CPU?

Comment: Of course, if you want to sort ten million numbers all within [0;99] you might want to use counting sort. (Yes, I'm aware I'm probably reading too much into a simple example.)

Comment: Basically I am performing Hyper quick sort on MPI with number of processors vary between 2-64. The code accepts and input file with random numbers to be sorted and creates a new sorted file. I am using random generator in C to generate numbers.

I have taken two kind of observations in my experiment, one with range 10^3 (i.e numbers within range 1-10^3) and other with range 10^8 and sorted total of 10^10 numbers of each type.

Comment: I got different time for each observation. I know hyperquick sorts, sorting time depends on pivot element and hence i am unable to find whether this range affects the output or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardware works with *bits*, not with decimal digits. Furthermore, the hardware always works with the same fixed amount of bits (for a given operation); smaller values are padded. For example, a 32 bit CPU usually has 32 bit comparator units with exactly as much circuitry needed for 32 bit comparisons, and uses those regardless of whether the values currently being compared would fit into fewer bits.

Another issue with your thinking is that the exact amount of logic gates doesn't matter much for performance. The propagation time of individual gates is much smaller than a clock cycle, only rather complicated circuits with long dependency chains actually take longer than a single cycle (and even then it might be pipelined to still get a throughput of 1 op per cycle). A surprisingly large number of logic gates *in sequence* (and an virtually unlimited number of logic gates *in parallel*) can easily finish their work within one clock cycle. Hence, a smart 64 bit comparison doesn't take more clock cycles than a 8 bit one.

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer**: It depends, but probably not

**The longer answer**:
It's hard to know because you haven't said much about the hardware or the sorting algorithm. You mentioned later that you're using some MPI variant of Quicksort. So you're asking if there could be a performance difference between 6-bit numbers and 3-bit numbers due to the hardware. Well, *if* you pack those digits together then you're going to have better bandwidth when transferring the dataset from memory to the processor. Since you haven't mentioned anything about compacted arrays, I'll assume you're not doing this. Once the value is in the register it will have the same latency and throughput regardless of being 6 bits or 3 bits.

There are algorithms like radix sort that perform differently depending on the number of bits needed for your range of numbers. Since you're not using this, it doesn't apply.

Comment: Thanks hayesti and delnan